# How to get a Map parameter in a REST service for different mime types?

Tags: java, rest, parameters, dictionary, jersey

How can I specify a map as one of the parameters of a REST service e.g

```
@Path("/servicepath")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class MyResource {
    @POST
    public Response getMap(Map<String, List<Object>>) {
    //code here
    }
}
```

or

```
@Path("/servicepath")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyResource {
    @POST
    public Response getMap(Map<String, List<Object>>) {
    //code here
    }
}
```

I am using Jersey. Should I implement a `MessageBodyReader` for that? But implementing a reader for a generic type like `Map` seems a bad way for me. Maybe I should write a wrapper class on top of the `Map` object.

What is your ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The JAX-RS specification (section 4.2.4) does require that implementors (like jersey) provide a `MessageBodyReader` implementation for `MultivaluedMap<String, String>` which is used to consume `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` mime types. So for example, you can do something like this:

```
@Path("/servicepath")
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String doTheFormThing(MultivaluedMap<String, String> formdata) {
    return formdata.toString();
}
```

Is this not sufficient for what you're trying to do?

Comment: what I want to do is getting a Map from different kinds of inputs like JSON, XML, etc.

Comment: I see. I guess you would have to do your own `MessageBodyReader` implementation.You'll need to define your own media type or use an existing one so that the semantics of the message are predictable. This is part of the REST uniform interface constraint.